# AngularJS - ui-router - MVC 5 - html5mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a mini SPA with **AngularJS** and **MVC 5**. In addition to that, I want to use **ui-router** plugin for AngularJS instead of ng-route and want to enable **html5mode**.

My problem is, whenever I click on an anchor element, it refreshes the page and sends request to ASP.NET MVC controller and puts the selected view in the right place, I want it not to reload.

If I change AngularJS routing mechanism to ng-route, then it works as I wanted, does not refreshes the page, and routes to the selected view.

In MVC 5 **RouteConfig.cs** file,

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SpaUI",
            url: "{SpaUI}/{*catchall}",
            defaults: new { controller = "SpaUI", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "SpaUI", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

---

In **app.js** file for AngularJS,

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$provide', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $provide, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Dashboard');

    $stateProvider
    .state("dashboard", {
        url: "/Dashboard",
        templateUrl: "AngularViews/dashboard.html"
    })

    .state("test", {
        url: "/Test",
        templateUrl: "AngularViews/test.html"
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 }]);
```

---

In **_Layout.cshtml** file for anchors;

```
 <a data-ui-sref="dashboard" title="Dashboard">
```

---

In same **_Layout.cshtml** file for view placeholder

```
 <div id="content" data-ui-view="" class="view-animate"></div>
```

---

How can I make all of these things play together without reloading the page? 
Any ideas are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It might help you!!

By doing this:

- Remove the "app" route complexity, and use the standard route.
- Add the rewrite rule.
- Remove the base href from the layout.

For example look like this.

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }).RouteHandler = new DashRouteHandler();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DashRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Custom route handler that removes any dashes from the route before handling it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requestContext">The context of the given (current) request.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var routeValues = requestContext.RouteData.Values;

        routeValues["action"] = routeValues["action"].UnDash();
        routeValues["controller"] = routeValues["controller"].UnDash();

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

etc.